# ¿Cómo obtener el ancho del texto de un textarea?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Lo que trato de hacer es obtener el ancho del texto del interior de un textarea, tengo este codigo:

```js
const txt = document.getElementsByTagName('textarea')[0];
txt.style.resize="none";
txt.style.background="transpartent";
txt.style.border="0";
txt.style.overflow="hidden";
txt.style.fontSize="20px";
var range = document.createRange();
range.selectNodeContents(txt.value);//No se si esto tiene mucho sentido la verdad
var rects = range.getClientRects();
console.log(rects[0].width);
```

```html
<textarea>Texto</textarea>
```

Intente hacerlo con el Range pero no se puede porque el contenido no es un Node y no se que hacer para ajustar el textarea al texto si no puedo obtener el ancho del texto y asignarlo al wdith del textarea. ¿Se les ocurre alguna otra manera de hacerlo?

Quería el ancho del texto porque luego tengo que cambiarle la fuente de dicho texto(Verdana, Monoespaciado). Muchisimas gracias por su ayuda!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No creo que se pueda medir el ancho de un texto dentro de un `textarea`, pero se me ocurre lo siguiente:

1. Crear un div auxiliar
2. En el div copiamos algunos estilos del textarea, como el `font-size` y el `font-family`
3. Colocamos el texto dentro del div
4. Obtenemos el `width` del div
5. Borramos el div

```js
const txt = document.querySelector('textarea');
const div_aux = document.createElement("div");
const estilo = getComputedStyle(txt); //obtenemos los estilos del textarea

div_aux.innerText = txt.value;
document.body.appendChild(div_aux);
div_aux.style.fontSize = estilo.fontSize;
div_aux.style.fontFamily = estilo.fontFamily;
div_aux.style.display ="inline-block";

const width = getComputedStyle(div_aux).width;
div_aux.remove();

console.log(width)
```

```html
<textarea style="font-size:24px">Texto</textarea>
```